# Plugging One Router into Another Router

Tags: router

Will pulling a wire from a router and plugging it into a wireless router slow down the internet connection?

Answer (score 3):

Not really - in general your LAN speeds are so much more than your internet connection speeds that it won't make a difference, unless of course your router was overloaded and started acting up

Don't forget to turn off DHCP on the second router.

Comment: It actually is best if the router has a "bridged mode" for this purpose. Not every router will, but it will simplify the setup if it is there.